# I'm having a hard time figuring out why I can't call from my dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

so I'm making a space invaders game, and I can't find out what I did wrong, I'm following a tutorial, everything should be the same as there but somehow for me it's not working.

Here's my main class:

```
class Ship:

    def __init__(self, x, y, color, health=100):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.health = health
        self.ship_img = None
        self.laser_img = None
        self.lasers = []
        self.cool_down_counter = 0
```

and subclass for ships:

```
class Enemy(Ship):

    SHIP_COLOR = {"r": (RED_SPACESHIP, RED_LASER), "b": (BLUE_SPACESHIP, BLUE_LASER), "g": (GREEN_SPACESHIP, GREEN_LASER)}
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, health=100):
        super().__init__(x, y, health)
        self.ship_img, self.laser_img = self.SHIP_COLOR(color)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)
```

so what I'm trying to do is generating a random color for the ships with this line:

```
enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100), random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(["r", "b", "g"]))
enemies.append(enemy)
```

The first to input are the coordinates basically and the 3rd one should pick the colour.
Random choice should pick a pair from the dictionary for ship and laser color, either red, green or blue.

Any help is appreciated, I'm trying since yesterday morning and I get the same error every time
(TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable)

Comment: change `self.SHIP_COLOR(color)` to `self.SHIP_COLOR[color]` since SHIP_COLOR is a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells the issue:

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

`self.SHIP_COLOR(color)` tries to "call" the dictionary as if it were a function. Use `[...]` to index the dictionary instead by changing `self.SHIP_COLOR(color)` to `self.SHIP_COLOR[color]`.

Comment: @JocoKiss you can mark this answer as accepted then.